# Django 'function' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a simple Django app where I want to display and save some data from a model.

This is my model

```
class Curr(models.Model):
name=models.TextField(default='USD')
value=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, default=0)
```

My Model Form

```
class CurrForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Curr
    fields = '__all__'
```

My View

```
currency = Curr.objects.all()
if request.method == "POST":
        post_values = request.POST.copy()
        form = CurrForm(post_values, instance=currency)
```

This gives the error

```
'function' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Reading the other similar posts did not clear my doubts. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `instance=currency[0]` instead of `instance=currency` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your instance are not all your Curr objects. You need to select a specific instance to operate through that object.

Example seen on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method :

```
# Create a form to edit an existing Article, but use
# POST data to populate the form.
a = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
f = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=a)
f.save()
```

Piece of advice: Use serializers. It will help you a lot to save data to python models and to get data from models to json/etc. (It uses Django Rest Framework).

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/